# How to change datetime.time return type to string under pyodbc?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have moved the codebase for a large existing Python 2 project from `pymssql` to `pyodbc`. The move was easy, everything builds, and runs fine, except that pyodbc returns SQL Server columns of type time as `datetime.time`, where pymssql (as well as the PostgreSQL native drivers) return strings.

Meaning, I receive a `datetime.time(11, 54, 13, 161000)` object instead of `11:54:13.161000`. Is there any way I can change this behavior globally without resorting to a stored procedure of some sort? Handling a returned object instead of a returned string will involve several days worth of refactoring and testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a pyodbc [Output Converter function](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Using-an-Output-Converter-function) to capture the TIME values returned from SQL Server and format them as strings.

Before:

```python
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLmyDb;', autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

rtn = crsr.execute("SELECT CAST('11:54:13.161' AS TIME)").fetchval()
print(repr(rtn))  # datetime.time(11, 54, 13, 161000)

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

After:

```python
import pyodbc
import struct


def time_as_string(raw_bytes):
    tup = struct.unpack("<4hI", raw_bytes)  # e.g., (11, 54, 13, 0, 161000000)
    tweaked = [tup[i] // 100 if i == 4 else tup[i] for i in [0, 1, 2, 4]]
    return "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}.{:07d}".format(*tweaked)


cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SQLmyDb;', autocommit=True)
cnxn.add_output_converter(pyodbc.SQL_SS_TIME2, time_as_string)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()

rtn = crsr.execute("SELECT CAST('11:54:13.161' AS TIME)").fetchval()
print(repr(rtn))  # '11:54:13.1610000'

crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: Yep - works like a charm - I Was reading through the docs when someone on github pointed me to the same thing - thanks!